# cannot understand the result of ruby logic operator

Tags: ruby, logic, operator-keyword

In Ruby, it is reasonable to find code like:

```
a = 1 and b = 2 and c = 3
print "a = #{a}, b = #{b}, c = #{c}\n"
```

gets the result:

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```

but I cannot understand why code like:

```
a = 1 && b = 2 && c = 3
print "a = #{a}, b = #{b}, c = #{c}\n"
```

the result is:

```
a = 3, b = 3, c = 3
```

Could anyone please clarify that for me?

Comment: Both pieces of code simply give a `SyntaxError` for me. I don't get the results you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for editing Andrew, it looks better

Answer (score 3):

It's about higher precedence of `&&` operator then `and`:

`a = 1 && b = 2 && c = 3`

is equivalent to

`a = (1 and b = (2 and c = 3))`

which results in

1. 3 is assigned to `c`
2. (2 and 3) which results in 3 is assigned to `b`
3. (1 and 3) which results in 3 is finally assigned to `a`

Comment: You don't explain why `2 && 3 == 3`

Comment: @Borodin Logical ```and``` evaluates its right argument only if the left operand is evaluated to ```true``` Which is valid for any object except ```nil``` or ```false```. Right operand is then the result of the expression. But I don't think it need to be mentioned in an answer to OP's question.

Comment: @Borodin Your insertion of inner-most parens in my answer find as quite redundant.

Comment: @DavidUnric: Fair enough, it is your answer. But we are talking about operator precedence here, and I see no reason why `2 and c = 3` isn't equal to `(2 and c) = 3`.

Comment: @DavidUnric: OK, so why does logical *and* *"evaluate its right argument only if the left operand is evaluated to true"*?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the priority of the operands, this behaviour is the result of the [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of logic operators.

When evauating `and`, if the first operand is found to be false, then there is no reason to evaluate the second. The value of `a and b` is therefore calculated as `a ? b : a`.

Likewise, the `or` operator contracts to `a ? a : b`.

These optimisations work fine logically, when we don't care about the specific value returned but only whether it is true or false. But it also allows for useful coding idioms, such as

```
( list = list || [] ) << item
```

which works because `list = list || []` is evaluated as `list = list` (a no-op) if `list` is true (non-nil), or `list = []` (creating a new empty array) if `list` has already been initialised, and so is *"true"*.

So an expression like `2 and (c = 3)` evaluates to `2 and 3` or `2 ? 3 : 2`, so `3`.